# Sencha ExtJS: MVC or no MVC

Tags: design-patterns, extjs4, extjs4.1

We have started building our RIA with ExtJS as a presentation tool, now question I have is with ExtJS 4.x we can break down our JS code into either regular way or MVC way.

Which approach shall one should go and under which circumstances?

We will be using JavaEE REST webservices (json) as data-source. Yes, our application will be data intensive and modular (with multiple high-level modules, no less than a dozen).

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I appreciate your help on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mostly depends on your level of Ext JS competence. If you're comfortable with the framework and understand how dynamic loading works then you'll probably do pretty well with MVC.

However if you're starting out with Ext JS (or alternatively, need a higher level of maturity from any third-party tools) you should probably stick with vanilla Ext JS. Everything you can do with MVC you can do without, and MVC introduces a new pattern of structuring files that will add to the learning curve.

Your decision should also factor in access to later versions of Ext JS 4.x. If you can get 4.1.3 (or even the new 4.2 beta) you will have much more success with MVC than if you used 4.1.0 or earlier. According to the release notes, 14 bugs in MVC alone were fixed in 4.1.2 and 4.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing a code from the beginning, I don't see the reason why not to use suggested, and well known practices like MVC pattern.

It is also recommended by Sencha team.

Comment: I am waiting if someone from Sencha team can get involve to answer this question. It's a choice and not a mandate, only reason for asking this question is it would end up one with too many files in javascript (controller, view, model etc)..!

Comment: If you have a large project, of course you will have plenty of files. But, what is a problem with that ? It is better to have a lot of files cleverly separated and organized, than to have all code in one file.

Comment: And, if you want somebody from Sencha team to answer your question, ask it on Sencha forum, not here ;)

Comment: you're right. I should have plugged this Q at sencha forum...but I wanted diversification probably and I trust SOF more in terms of response.! So thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the MVC approach to better separate the specific functions of your code and application.

It allows new developers to know where to look for specific functionality (speeding up adoption) and where to place new functionality.

The Ext loader makes it easy to work with many files, and if you feel that too many files are an issue, then compress them into a single file before deployment.

Many smaller files would always be preferred to fewer larger files in my book.

Answer (score 2):

I always choose a modular approach to MVC development with ExtJS 4 (or any framework for that matter). ExtJs 4 documentation can lead one who has never built multiple Enterprise level single page web applications to believe that the only design pattern one CAN use with ExtJS is to put:

1. All Controllers in a controllers folder
2. All Models in a models folder
3. All Stores in a stores folder
4. All Views in a views folder

But anyone with enough years of experience will probably tell you that that is a poor design pattern.

A Modular MVC Design pattern would amplify a strong decoupling of concerns by leaning on local and global level eventing. It Splits the Web Application up into small manageable parts (small applications brought together to make the large application based on a JSON Configuration object handed down from the bottom tier based on a user's credentials). It allows one to add new features to a large application without breaking other existing features. It makes bug fixes a more focused task. It also creates a common pattern which makes unit testing before or after the fact very easy.

I've yet to see many articles on implementing a Modular Design Pattern with ExtJS 4. I learned how to do it from 6 years of programming with ESRI's Javavscript API. It made my life a whole lot easier. And it made Javascript development of Enterprise level Single Page Web Applications fun.